# Cakephp Xml to Array to Database

Tags: xml, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-1.3

this is the first time using CakePHP's XML functions.

I have set up this model:

```
<?php
class Importer extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Importer';
    var $useTable = false;

    function import_deals(){
        // import XML class
        App::import('Xml');

        // your XML file's location
        $file = "../webroot/files/datafeed_114532.xml";

        // now parse it
        $parsed_xml =& new XML($file);
        $parsed_xml = Set::reverse($parsed_xml); // this is what i call magic

        // see the returned array
        debug($parsed_xml);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class ImporterController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Importer';
    var $uses = array('Importer', 'City', 'Deal', 'Partner');

    function import_deals($parsed_xml) {
        $this->loadModel('Importer');
        $deals = $this->Importer->find('all');

        $this->set('deals', $deals);
    }
}
```

The view I am not sure about because I basically want it to put the XML data into the database. The XML array looks like:

```
Array (
    [MerchantProductFeed] => Array (
        [Merchant] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 2891
                [Prod] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                        [id] => 175029851
                        [web_offer] => yes
                        [Text] => Array (
                            [name] => London South: 60%   Off Takeaways From Just-Eat
                            [desc] => £6 for £15 Worth of Takeaways From Over 1000 London Eateries with Just-Eat
                            [promo] => 60 %
                        )
                        [Uri] => Array (
                            [awTrack] => http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=175029851&a=114532&m=2891
                            [mImage] => http://static.groupon.co.uk/44/30/1311759403044.jpg
                        )
                        [Price] => Array (
                            [rrp] => 15.00
                        )
                        [Cat] => Array (
                            [awCatId] => 100
                            [awCat] => Bodycare & Fitness
                            [mCat] => Deals
                        )
                        [brand] => Array ()
                        [valFrom] => 2011-07-29
                        [valTo] => 2011-10-29
                    )
                    [1] => Array (
                        [id] => 175030161
                        [web_offer] => yes
                        [Text] => Array (
                            [name] => Essex: Up to 70% Off Treatment and Cut and Blowdry OR Half Head Highlights or Colour
                            [desc] => Cut, Blow Dry and Paul Mitchell Treatment (£18) Or Add Half Head of Highlights or Colour (£34) at Cube (Up to 70% Saving)
                            [promo] => 70 %
                        )
                        [Uri] => Array (
                            [awTrack] => http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=175030161&a=114532&m=2891
                            [mImage] => http://static.groupon.co.uk/53/51/1311615285153.jpg
                        )
                        [Price] => Array (
                            [rrp] => 60.00
                        )
                        [Cat] => Array (
                            [awCatId] => 100
                            [awCat] => Bodycare & Fitness
                            [mCat] => Deals
                        )
                        [brand] => Array ()
                        [valFrom] => 2011-07-29
                        [valTo] => 2011-10-28
                    )
                    ....
```

Any help would be appreciated, even if you can point me in right direction :) Thanks guys

Dave

Comment: so what's the problem? You got the data, you can do a save to your model to save it in database.

Comment: but how will it know where to put the data lol cause that data has got to be put into multiple tables and fields :)

Comment: you tell it :)) ok, I'll post my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Importer model

> ```
> var $uses = array('City', 'Deal', 'Partner');
>  function import_deals() {
>    App::import('Xml');
>    $file = "../webroot/files/datafeed_114532.xml";
>    $xml_obj =& new XML($file);
>    $parsed_xml = Set::reverse($xml_obj); 
>    // set up the data here and save
> }
> ```

Basically, if the xml data is not in the same format as the database tables (which I guess it is, based on your data), you'll have to loop through $parsed_xml to construct the correct data format to save in your model. I don't know your tables schema, so that's the general direction.

Comment: Ok, thats great that i can eliminate model lol, so ive got that and the array but its the looping through it to get it into the format my tables use that im stuck with. EG. the deals table has id, title, highlights, fineprint, description, price, rrp_price <<< these are different from the array lol :P Thanks

Comment: then post your tables schema.

Comment: do you just want the tables and fields in my db ?

Comment: if you want me to help with converting the data to save to these tables, then I need to know what fields they have.

Comment: if you can email me @ admin@amazingvouchercodes.co.uk i can send u .sql file :)